# Building Qt 4.8 with mingw fails - "I couldn't find a pro file for QtCore module"

Tags: qt

I'm trying to re-build Qt 4.8.0 in Windows statically.  I'm following the documentation here: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.8-snapshot/deployment-windows.html. After typing config -static in a mingw terminal at C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\mingw, I get the following error:

Running syncqt...
I couldn't find a pro file for QtCore module
syncqt failed, return code 2

I've been looking all over and can't figure out where to go from here!  IMO the Qt documentation is not very good in this regard.

Thanks!

Marlon

Comment: Did you ever get this figured? I'm running into a similar problem (except I use VS2010)

Comment: [Answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9836761/594137)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to configure Qt for static building](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835906/unable-to-configure-qt-for-static-building)