# Unable to configure Qt for static building

Tags: qt, static-linking, qmake

Essentially this is a repost of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221012/building-qt-4-8-with-mingw-fails-i-couldnt-find-a-pro-file-for-qtcore-module) which was never answered. I am trying to set up Qt for static linking following these instructions.
So far, all I've done is go to where my Qt version is, and run

```
configure -static
```

I get some output, ending in:

```
Sources are in..............C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\msvc2010
Build is done in............C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\msvc2010
Install prefix..............C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\msvc2010
Headers installed to........C:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/msvc2010/include
Libraries installed to......C:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/msvc2010/lib
Plugins installed to........C:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/msvc2010/plugins
Imports installed to........C:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/msvc2010/imports
Binaries installed to.......C:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/msvc2010/bin
Docs installed to...........C:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/msvc2010/doc
Data installed to...........C:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/msvc2010
Translations installed to...C:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/msvc2010/translations
Examples installed to.......C:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/msvc2010/examples
Demos installed to..........C:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/msvc2010/demos

WARNING: Using static linking will disable the use of plugins.
     Make sure you compile ALL needed modules into the library.
Running syncqt...
I couldn't find a pro file for QtCore module
syncqt failed, return code 9
```

Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a known issue compiling Qt 4.8.0 from source.
Just delete syncqt.* in qt bin folder :

http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/12/15/qt-4-8-0-released/#comment-49942
http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/12/15/qt-4-8-0-released/#comment-49951
http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/12/15/qt-4-8-0-released/#comment-49953

Comment: thanks for the help. That solved that problem, but now there's something else going on. Can you please have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858331/qmake-gives-code-3-when-attempting-to-configure-qt-for-static-building)?

Comment: Holy cow...how did I only just find the answer here? BTW, this happened to me on 4.8.1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same situation of user963258 and I get the same error.
I deleted syncqt.* from qt bin folder, but I then get the same error

[qmake gives code 3 when attempting to configure qt for static building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858331/qmake-gives-code-3-when-attempting-to-configure-qt-for-static-building)

Why Qt4.8 has so many issues?