# qmake gives code 3 when attempting to configure qt for static building

Tags: visual-studio, qt, static-linking

I have the latest Qt SDK. I'm trying to configure it for static building with VS2010 (dynamic linking works fine) I have it at this location: C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\msvc2010

When I go there with the VS2010 command prompt and try to run configure -static, or configure -static I get some output but in the end it fails with

```
Generating Makefiles...
 WARNING: c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\msvc2010\projects.pro:44: Unable to find file
 for inclusion src\src.pro
WARNING: c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\msvc2010\projects.pro:46: Unable to find file
 for inclusion doc\doc.pri
Reading C:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/msvc2010/tools
Reading C:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/msvc2010/translations/translations.pro
Reading C:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/msvc2010/examples
Reading C:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/msvc2010/demos
Qmake failed, return code 3
```

Please help

Comment: I'm in your same situation. It's an hell!

Comment: @linello check out my answer below. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I downloaded the source zip file instead of trying to work with what came in the SDK and it's working now. Just download the source from [here](http://qt-project.org/downloads), unzip it, and run the configure.exe in the unzipped folder. My guess (although I have inspected this) is that there's missing source files or other resources in the SDK version.

Comment: I had this problem at one point and fixed by ensuring I downloaded the larger offline version.